# Specify Routes in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm creating Restful web services using Flask.
From the examples I see we use annotations like

@app.route('/')

I wanted to know how I use this if I have two Classes. I tried moving that to a different file inside a package but then it gives me a 404 error.

Contents of Service.py

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'
```

Contents of Flask.py

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

I just want to know how do I specify routes if they are in different classes.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question corretly. How does your two classes look like? For me it sounds like you want to use `Pluggable Views`: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/views/

Comment: @ChristianEichelmann: no views. just services like Student/add Student/delete Student/update Teacher/find Teacher/activate

Comment: It would be helpful to see the rest of the code that acutally produces the 404.

Comment: @ChristianEichelmann can you just fix the above code. Should u require anything plz let me know. I shall provide that. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not define `app` in both modules.  Only define it in one place and import it everywhere else.  In the module that defines `app`, import your other modules *after* defining it, to avoid circular imports.

A basic structure for a Flask project looks like:

```
MyProject/
    my_package/
        __init__.py
        service.py
    run.py
```

`MyProject/my_package/__init__.py`

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

from my_project import service
```

`MyProject/my_package/service.py`

```
from my_project import app


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'
```

`MyProject/run.py`

```
from my_package import app

app.run('localhost', debug=True)
```

Use `python run.py` from the `MyProject` directory to run the application with the dev server.

---

<sub>You also have some terminology errors.  They're called "decorators", not "annotations".  They're called "modules", not "classes".  Also, common practice is to give files lowercase names.</sub>